# Black screen after 16.04 install

Tags: boot, 16.04, drivers

After I did a fresh install of 16.04, I got a black screen. I got tired of waiting, so I turned my laptop off and on again. The second time around, I got to the log-in screen. I installed the proprietary software via Software & Updates, but is there something else I should be doing?

I saw some suggestions for using `nomodeset`. Should I do that? Should I use the Boot-Repair tool?

I looked through the forum and saw that people were having issues with installing the Nvidia drivers, but I don't think my laptop uses/needs them, so I'm not sure what the error is.

I'm a new user to Ubuntu, and I just want to make sure I have a smooth experience. Thanks!

**edit** Here are the [results](http://paste2.org/wCm2jeMI) of running Boot Repair. Also, I noticed now that there's a flicker when I get to the log-in screen. E.g., the "old" background shows up, there's a flicker, and then the screen is updated with my "new" background.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: This is the result from Boot Repair: [link](http://paste2.org/wCm2jeMI)

Comment: [Edit] your question with the corrected link, not in the comments section, so anyone can easily see it :)

Comment: @M.Becerra Got it; I'll make sure to put in the question. Thanks!